# Why don't PHP developers cache their methods?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm hoping this question isn't too opinionated for StackOverflow, it seems like there's a correct answer here that I just can't see.

I've seen a few other languages do this, but PHP is the one I'm looking at now. This question stems from me looking at the Magento 2 source code:

```
<?php
class Image extends AbstractHelper implements ArgumentInterface
{

    // ...

    protected function setImageProperties()
    {
        $this->_getModel()->setDestinationSubdir($this->getType());
        $this->_getModel()->setWidth($this->getWidth());
        $this->_getModel()->setHeight($this->getHeight());

        // Set 'keep frame' flag
        $frame = $this->getFrame();
        $this->_getModel()->setKeepFrame($frame);

        // Set 'constrain only' flag
        $constrain = $this->getAttribute('constrain');
        if (null !== $constrain) {
            $this->_getModel()->setConstrainOnly($constrain);
        }

        // Set 'keep aspect ratio' flag
        $aspectRatio = $this->getAttribute('aspect_ratio');
        if (null !== $aspectRatio) {
            $this->_getModel()->setKeepAspectRatio($aspectRatio);
        }

        // Set 'transparency' flag
        $transparency = $this->getAttribute('transparency');
        if (null !== $transparency) {
            $this->_getModel()->setKeepTransparency($transparency);
        }

        // Set background color
        $background = $this->getAttribute('background');
        if (null !== $background) {
            $this->_getModel()->setBackgroundColor($background);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

([Taken from github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Helper/Image.php#L218-L253))

Again and again, you see `$this->_getModel()`. I'd have thought it would be more efficient to store the results of that method in a variable and then call it as needed:

```
<?php
class Image extends AbstractHelper implements ArgumentInterface
{

    // ...

    protected function setImageProperties()
    {
        $model = $this->_getModel();
    
        $model->setDestinationSubdir($this->getType());
        $model->setWidth($this->getWidth());
        $model->setHeight($this->getHeight());

        // ...
    }
```

And yet, I rarely see server-side programmers do this. Is there a reason why they don't? Is it considered more readable? Does the compiler abstract away the overhead so the two options are as efficient as each other (or even more efficient since there's no variable assignment)?

Comment: You mean like line 485 in the same source you link to.  IMHO it's a style that some people use and so probably does come down to opinion.  I prefer to store the (in this example) model and work with that.

Comment: Who sad that Magento 2 is the bible of PHP? I would recommend your approach. Though maybe the Magento 2 implementation of $this->_getModel() has almost no overhead, this is not visible.

Comment: I don't like Magento 2, but for my sins I'm stuck developing with it. It's just something that I've noticed and M2 happened to be the code example that I had to hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran some tests on the looping to conclude when to performance

```
class Test{
    private function someFunc()
    {
        $myString = "any string";
        return $myString;
    }
    public function doTestCall()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i < 150000; $i++) {
            $x = $this->someFunc();
        }
    }
    
    public function doTestWithoutCall()
    {
        $y = $this->someFunc();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 150000; $i++) {
            //nothing
        }
    }
}

doTestCall: 0.25357
doTestWithoutCall: 0.019944
```

and again:

```
doTestCall: 0.250552
doTestWithoutCall: 0.019927
```

and again:

```
doTestCall: 0.24839
doTestWithoutCall: 0.020015
```

When the loop ran a million times:

```
doTestCall: 0.45552
doTestWithoutCall: 0.134747


doTestCall: 0.47562
doTestWithoutCall: 0.129841
```

From this it can be concluded that data retention is fasterת However at rather negligible periods of time - if it is a function that does not perform a complex operation.
So I allow myself to assume that the preference is for a more readable code